# Angular 14 ng build --configuration production after upgrading

Tags: javascript, angular

Recently I update my project from ng 13 to ng 14.
What I execute ng build --configuration production, CLI creates some compiled and minimized js files.
One of the minimized files was scripts.js.
When I deploy it in IIS it is crushed and not displayed on the browser.
One of the errors in the console was :
[Unexpected token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTfK5.png)

The project was **not** compiled well and I saw that when I execute ng build without --production, the js if different and OK.

Does anyone face this issue?

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "knesset-website-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^3.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^7.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^7.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^7.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^5.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^7.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^9.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^7.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pager": "^4.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^4.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^7.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.3",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^0.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@videogular/ngx-videogular": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-v4-rtl": "^4.6.0-2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dashjs": "^4.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hls.js": "^1.1.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.1.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^10.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.6",
    "scriptjs": "^2.5.9",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.6",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.3"
  }
}
```